# Hibernate all-delete-orphan for ordered collections

Tags: java, hibernate, linkedhashset, all-delete-orphan

I have a relationship like

```
<set name="someBeans" table="sometable" cascade="all, delete-orphan" inverse="true" lazy="true">
        <key column="some_id" />
        <one-to-many class="someBean" />
    </set>
```

in my Java code there was a set performed on this which was like

```
myClass.setSomeBeans(SomeBeans);
```

now this SomeBeans is a linkedHashmap and so the order was maintained, however because of all Delete Orphan being used in cascade i was getting exception in a particular scenario as :

```
HibernateException – A collection with cascade=”all-delete-orphan” was no longer referenced by the owning entity instance
```

So i changed the java implementation above to

```
myClass.getSomeBeans().clear();
myClass.getSomeBeans().addAll(SomeBeans)
```

However doing this i am not able to sustain the order from linkedHashMap SomeBeans.

Has anyone faced such issue as well, any help in this regard would be appriciated

Regards,

Vaibhav

Comment: When Hibernate will load the collection from the database, it won't use a LinkedHashSet, and the order is thus arbitrary. Why would you want to preserve it in this particular case? Relying on the insertion order in a set maintained by Hibernate doesn't make much sense.

Comment: The order is stored in a different table and so i need to apply that order to SomeBeans and then perform a SetSomeBeans() in my java code which started giving the exception mentioned above to i tried the way of clear() and then addAll(), hibernate does not preserve the order and thus the solution messed up with the order of SomeBeans.

Comment: You haven't understood. Let's say Hibernate takes your set as is, and persists the association. Now you start a new transaction, and reload the entity and its set from the database. Hibernate won't magically preserve the order of the beans in the set. It will create a non-ordered, non-linkled set, and the order of the entities will be arbitrary. So relying on the insertion order of the entities is foolish.

Comment: Thanks for your inputs on this but i get a feel that this is heading to a wrong direction, i said it worked fine for me when i used the simple set operation of bean, however this threw me the exception related to all delete orphan for which i tried clear() and addAll() which messed up the order.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to accomplish what i wanted to i created a dummy object copied the properties from the hibernate Object and applied the sorting on it, which got preserved and all delete orphan related problem was also taken care of.